# friend declaration invokes "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations"

Tags: forward-declaration

When I only include my "Int.h", friend declaration invokes "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations". And it runs well when I just write forward declaration "class Int;" and include "Int.h" in cpp file.

```
#ifndef _MY_ARRAY_H_
#define _MY_ARRAY_H_
// class Int;
#include "Int.h"

class MyArray {
    friend Int; //error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
public:
    MyArray(int dim, int *size);
    Int operator[](int n);
private:
    int mDim;
    int *mSize;
    int *mData;
};
#endif
```

In my opinion, it doesn't need "forward declaration", because there is a "Int" class declaration in the "Int.h" file. But it does. Why?

Comment: And I include "MyArray.h" in "Int.h" also.

Comment: We cannot evaluate your code when you've only provided part of it.  We need to see `Int.h`, too, to determine what's going on.

Comment: @이태윤: Do you really mean, that `MyArray.h` includes `Int.h` and also `Int.h` includes `MyArray.h`? If yes, these cyclic dependencies would be perfect explanation for the need of the forward declaration.